# Select random values from an array in ascending and descending order

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, random

In JavaScript, I'm trying to select random elements from an array, either in ascending and descending order. I would like to create a function that takes an array to select from, the number of elements to select and the random order (either ascending or descending). How can I go about doing this?

e.g

```
let ar = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l]


selectRandom(ar, 4, 'ascending')
// returns [b,e,f,j]

selectRandom(ar, 6, 'descending')
// returns [l,j,f,e,b,a]
```

Comment: *up* is 4 but suddenly hey here's `1,3,6,8,11`

Comment: I guess 11 is where down would start if that makes sense?

Comment: That means *up = 4* is secretly disguised as `5`? or it's treated as some sort of index?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: What do you mean @ScottSauyet ?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service.  We expect you to try it first, and then to show some attempt in the question, noting where you are stuck.  Many people here could write a selectRandom function that works.  The goal is to help you write your own.

Comment: oh sorry, I thought the question had to be super concise so I omitted any attempts I made

Comment: if you [edit] the question to include your attempt, others might vote to reopen it, and you could get some additional answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could build random arrays and sort them as result.

```js
const
    getValues = (array, size) => {
        const values = new Set;

        while (values.size < size) values.add(array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]);
        return [...values];
    },
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    up = 4,
    down = 7,
    result = [
        ...getValues(array, up).sort((a, b) => a - b),
        ...getValues(array, down).sort((a, b) => b - a)
    ];

console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

const up = 4
const down = 7

let outputRadnomUpDown = new Array(up).fill(null).map(() => array[~~(Math.random() * array.length)]).sort(function(a, b){return a-b}).concat(new Array(down).fill(null).map(() => array[~~(Math.random() * array.length)]).sort(function(a, b){return b-a}));

console.log(outputRadnomUpDown);
```

PS: I've edited the answer because by mistake I've switch the number of up/down elements in my previous proposition.